# The DB2 SQL script is hanging in shell script, but working successfully in command line

Tags: sql, shell, db2

I have a DB2 script to first drop and then create some table spaces and functions. I can run the SQL script successfully in DB2 command line on the targeted database.

I need to execute this SQL script in a shell script multiple times. It can be executed successfully the first time, then it will hang at the second/third time. The command to execute the SQL script is very simple:
db2 CONNECT TO ktest4
db2 -v -f /tmp/sql/application_system/opmdb2_privilege_remove.sql.5342

I use DB2 9.7.8, and LINUX operating system. When the SQL script is hanged, I can still manually run the SQL script successfully in DB2 command line on the targeted database.

Does anyone know the reason? Thanks.

Xiaoyang Gao

Comment: Please add more information, like the exact command being ran on both commandline and the shell script.

Also, for debugging purposes, try running only a handful of the commands on the shellscript to try to find the problematic command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure DB2 is blocking? Did you put a semicolon between commands

```
db2 CONNECT TO ktest4 ; db2 -v -f /tmp/sql/application_system/opmdb2_privilege_remove.sql.5342
```

In order to trace the execution, I advise you to put some output, in order to detect where is it blocking

```
date ; db2 -r /tmp/output.log CONNECT TO ktest4 ; db2 -r /tmp/output.log values current timestamp ; db2 -r /tmp/output.log -v -f /tmp/sql/application_system ; db2 -r /tmp/output.log values current timestamp ; db2 -r /tmp/output.log terminate
```

With a command like this, you will save all outputs, and then you could check where is the error.

Comment: The DB2 is not blocking, just the SQL script is hanged. When the SQL script is hanged, I can log in the DB and manually run the SQL script in command line.

Comment: The SQL script is simple:

DROP TABLESPACE XXX
DROP BUFFERPOOL YYY
CONNECT RESET
TERMINATE


I manually run the "DROP TABLESPACE XXX" command in the command line, it will cause error:

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0290N  Table space access is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=55039


But, it does not explain why the SQL script is hanged.